# Query on large, indexed table times out

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, database-indexes

I am relatively new to using Postgres, but am wondering what could be the workaround here.

I have a table with about 20 columns and 250 million rows, and an index created for the timestamp column `time` (but no partitions).

Queries sent to the table have been failing (although using the view first/last 100 rows function in PgAdmin works), running endlessly.  Even simple `select *` queries.

For example, if I want to LIMIT a selection of the data to 10

```
SELECT * from mytable
WHERE time::timestamp < '2019-01-01'
LIMIT 10;
```

Such a query hangs - what can be done to optimize queries in a table this large?  When the table was of a smaller size (~ 100 million rows), queries would always complete.  What should one do in this case?

Comment: `time` is a bad column name for a time stamp field. And: you don't need the cast. (it might render your query insargeable.) Plus: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes no sense .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `time` is of data type `timestamp` or the index is created on `(time::timestamp)`, the query should be fast as lightning.

Please show the `CREATE TABLE` and the `CREATE INDEX` statement, and the `EXPLAIN` output for the query for more details.

Comment: I don’t remember the exact CREATE INDEX command- it is indeed of type timestamp and the index was created on that very same column

Comment: indexing will not always give guaranteed performance boosts.. There is a thing called optimizer which can choose not using a index when a full table access is faster. keep in mind that a index lookup in a B-tree index can make 1 or more random (disk) I/O to lookup.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That is technically true, but how could a sequential scan be faster than an index scan for the query in the question?

Comment: @the_darkside You could run `\d mytable` in `psql`, that would contain all the required information.

Comment: true i should have said  for example a full table access scan is faster.. Besides `2019-01-01` is close to the current date so i assumed `time::timestamp < '2019-01-01'` matched almost the complete table..

Comment: To be honest i totally overlooked that the query had a `LIMIT` clause..

Answer (score 0):

"Query that doesn't complete" usually means that it does disk swaps. Especially when you mention the fact that with 100M rows it manages to complete. That's because index for 100M rows still fits in your memory. But index twice this size doesn't.

Limit won't help you here, as database probably decides to read the index first, and that's what kills it.

You could try and increase available memory, but partitioning would actually be the best solution here.

Partitioning means smaller tables. Smaller tables means smaller indexes. Smaller indexes have better chances to fit into your memory.

Comment: There is very little correct information in this answer; it is misleading and should be deleted. Partitioning only improves speed for sequential scans. Indexes are not cached wholesale, but blockwise like everything else.

Comment: Partition will actually improve time for all type of scans, as long as you hit a limited number of them.

Comment: Can you explain that? How will partitioning improve the speed of an index scan noticably?

Comment: PostgreSQL supports native partition pruning in the latests versions @LaurenzAlbe which i think Alexey Soshin means with "hit a limited number of them"

Comment: With partition pruning, an index scan on a partitioned table will only have to scan a single index, so it might be as fast as an index scan on the unpartitioned table. But the planning time will increase. So at best we will have the same performance. If the partitioned index happens to be one level less deep, you might even win a millisecond or so in the index scan.